# How to open link in a new tab using custom field in wordpress using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to redirect all wordpress post permalinks to a custm field value instead of wordpress url with the below funciton:

```
function get_custom_permalink() {
global $wp_rewrite,$post;
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true);
$field =  $custom_field;
if (!empty($custom_field)) {
    return str_ireplace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $field);
 } else {
    return false;
 }
}
add_filter('post_link', 'get_custom_permalink', 10, 4);
```

The function works great but I'm not able to open in a new tab do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: So it works great, or doesn't (do you see in rendered HTML source `target="_blank"`)?

Comment: Works great in the same tab not in a new tab, so in the html source I do not see it

Comment: What you want to do depends on the theme you are using. You will need to check the theme and update the HTML code for the templates either by hooks or creating custom templates, that depends on the theme way of the HTML code wrapping over the posts

Comment: In the title of the question Im so clear Iwant to do it via php without editing theme or adding javascript if you have any suggestion in the shared code thanks. The filter works fine to replace permalink with the custom field value so the only thing that I have to learn is the str_ireplace which one is not working for me

Comment: Do you know any other method to add in my function?

Comment: @SHB: I’m not wp developer, what is in $field? Is there really string <a href=...>?

Comment: no there is just the url https://example.tld

Comment: @SHB: so if there is just URL, then there is no `<a ...` and your replace replace nothing (no pattern found).

Comment: post_link filter replaces the permalink url with the custom field value

Comment: @SHB: Try to read once again what I've wrote. If in `$field` is string like `'http:...'`, there is no replacement done (no `<a` found). Than it's obvious it can't work (you're trying to replace in place where is no `a` tag exists). I don't know how to do it better while I'm not a WP developer, but you need to trace where `a` tag is added and there make replacement `<a` to `<a target="_blank"`.

Comment: Yes I know Im wrong there thats why Im trying to ask here do you have any other idea or method without going to touch theme loop files but doing it with just this function, any other suggestion should I move strl_replace to any other place in the function or I have to add additional codes there to make it working as I want?